# Vector bundle defined by using divisors of very ample line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve. Suppose that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are line bundles on $X$, and $L_1$ is very ample.
$\operatorname{Div}(s)$ denotes a divisor defined by a global section $s\in H^0(X,L)$.
I want to prove the following claim.

> Set $W=H^0(X,L_1)\oplus H^0(X,L_2)$, and $\Gamma=\{((s_1,s_2),x)\in W\times X\mid \operatorname{Div}(s_1)\geq 2x\, and\, \operatorname{Div}(s_2)\geq x\}\subset W\times X$
> Then, $\Gamma\rightarrow X$ is a vector bundle of rank $dim\,W-3$.

This may be obvious from the definition of very ample, but I don't know how to use the condition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need $L_2$ to be globally generated. Then your vector bundle is a direct sum $E_1\oplus E_2$, with $(E_1)_x=H^0(L_1(-2x))$ and $(E_2)_x=H^0(L_2(-x))$. To define them globally, let $p,q$ be the 2 projections from $X\times X$ to $X$, $\Delta \subset X\times X$ the diagonal; then $E_1=q_*(p^*L_1(-2\Delta ))$, $E_2=q_*(p^*L_2(-\Delta ))$.

Comment: Thanks. But why do I need the condition that $L_{2}$ is generated by global sections ?

Comment: To ensure $h^0(L_2(-x))=h^0(L_2)-1$ for all $x$.